# How to avoid an empty result with `Bag.take(n)` when using dask?

Tags: python, bag, dask

Context:
Dask documentation states clearly that `Bag.take()` will only collect from the first partition. However, when using a filter it can occur that the first partition is empty, while others are not.

Question: 
Is it possible to use `Bag.take()` so that it collects from a sufficient number of partitions to collect the `n` items (or the maximum available less than than `n`).

Comment: Thanks for reading the documentation before posting!  This makes me happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
from toolz import take
f = lambda seq: list(take(n, seq))
b.reduction(f, f)
```

This grabs the first n elements of each partition, collects them all together, and then takes the first n elements of the result.

Comment: this didn't work! using tools version 0.8.0, dask 0.10, python 3.5.2  
`tb = db.from_sequence(range(20),npartitions = 4)`  
`tb.reduction(take(2),take(2)`  
gives  
PicklingError: Cannot pickle objects of type <class 'itertools.islice'>  
- I do appreciate your help..

Comment: Ah, pickling is odd.  Perhaps use `f = lambda seq: list(take(n, seq))` and `b.reduction(f, f)` instead.

Comment: this did it. and, yes I've read elsewhere of the charms of pickle, alarmingly it was from a post now several years old.