# does npartitions influence the result of dask.dataframe.head()?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

When running the following code, the result of dask.dataframe.head() depends on npartitions:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [2,3,4]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions = 3)
print(ddf.head())
```

This yields the following result:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
```

However, when I set npartitions to 1 or 2, I get the expected result:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

It seems to be important, that npartitions is lower than the length of the dataframe. Is this intended?

Comment: All your data (rows) is still there, though it won't be shown completely by `.head()`, `.tail()`, etc. But if you save it using `to_hdf()`, `to_csv()`, etc. then __all__ rows will be written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation [`dd.head()`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.head) only checks the first partition:

> `head(n=5, compute=True)`
>
> First n rows of the dataset
>
> Caveat, this only checks the first n rows of the first partition.

So the answer is yes, `dd.head()` is influenced by how many partitions are there in your dask dataframe.

*However* the number of rows in the first partition is expected to be larger than the number of rows you usually want to show when using `dd.head()` — otherwise using dask shouldn't pay off. The only common case when this might not be true is when taking the first `n` rows/elements after filtering, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38254247/356729).